# Bootstrap - get text on right of a left aligned form label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in Bootstrap which features some text inputs like so

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Category</label>
   <select class="form-control">
       <option>A</option>
       <option>B</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I want a link to appear on the right of the label so the user can edit the list of categories.

Is there any way to do this easily in Bootstrap, or should I add custom CSS, or do it a different way altogether?

I can't get this to render what I want but it would be like this:

**Category**____________________***Edit Categories***

[ select (A, B, etc)_________________________ ]

Comment: Use a `<span>` tag? Like this... http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/PGLYAV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label">
    <label>Category</label>
    <a href="#" class="pull-right">edit category</a>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
  </div>
   <select class="form-control">
       <option>A</option>
       <option>B</option>
   </select>
</div>
```